# Difference between 2^0*2 and (2^0)*2?

Tags: java, operators, expression

I have expected both expression's will give same answer:

```
System.out.println(2^0*2);
System.out.println((2^0)*2);
```

Output:

```
2
4
```

Is there a specific reason why `2^0*2 = 2` and `(2^0)*2 = 4`?

Comment: Please restrict yourself to one language only.  A question that asks about two language is too broad.

Comment: `*` has higher precedence than `^`. Most likely what you intended was `Math.pow(2, 0) * 2`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have wrongly assumed that `^` operator behaves the same like the exponentiation in math.

At the first sight you can see that `^` is understood as `+` operator. Actually it means bitwise `XOR` operator.

```
System.out.println(2^0*2);   //  2 XOR 0  * 2 = 2
System.out.println((2^0)*2); // (2 XOR 0) * 2 = 4
System.out.println(2^4);     //  2 XOR 4      = 6
```

The XOR is exclusive disjunction that outputs true only when inputs differ. Here is the whole trick:

```
2^0 = 2 XOR 0 = (0010) XOR (0000) = (0010) = 2 
2^4 = 2 XOR 4 = (0010) XOR (0100) = (0110) = 6
```

Answer (score 2):

check this link

http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php

2^0*2=2

- has higher priority thatn ^ so first you will evaluate 0*2 which is 0 and then xor it with 2 which will resutl 2

(2^0)*2

() has higher priority so you will first evaluate 2^0 then which is 2 then multiply it with 2

Comment: and where i exactly mentioned that is power operator, i mentioned that its xor

Comment: NO check the link it specifies different meanings of '^'

Answer (score -3):

[Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

In your first example you calculate: 0*2 = 2 ^ 0 = 2

In your second example you calculate: 2 ^ 0 = 2 * 2 = 4